# overflow scroll starts at specific height

Tags: html, css

In my website i am using 12 image with scroll

My problem is when I try to scroll from the top it dosen't work. When pointer reach at specific height scroll starts

When i tried to decrease size of the browser it worked fine

Check my markup and css

Markup

```
<div class="ebroc">
  <ul class="images">
    <li><img/></li>
    <li><img/></li>
    <li><img/></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul.images {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
ul.images li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
}
ul.images li img {
  height: 40vw;
  width: 100%;
}
.ebroc {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 70vw;
}
```

Comment: as i checked, it is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/fnvmqga8/ check this fiddle with your code. please point out what exactly is the problem

Comment: on small screen height it work fine ... but when i use it on big screen height it scroll start at the half size of `.ebroc`  height.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dMlPJAE.png still looks fine. maybe i didn't understand you or something is not right with your browser

Comment: well... let me check it on other computer

Comment: that would be better. and if possible show me the screenshot of how it looks like

Comment: Did you want the height to be vw or vh? https://jsfiddle.net/hbtoj3jv/

Comment: I want it to be `vw`